# How to code a particular javascript/ajax function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Thanks in anticipation all,

am a total novice in Ajax but i know this can be done, that's why I resort to asking instead of spending countless minutes google searching to no avail,

I have a link that I created which uses `onclick="return newWin(\'record.html\',800,600);"` and some javascript functions to open a new window/tab (record.html).

Then I know how to use another javascripts function to close the window on clicking a button

Now what am trying to figure out is this -

I have a form in which i use to post something to my database on the new window that pops out - now the form Is processed using PHP, alright the queries and all that is working but what I want to do is this

I want it that once the window pops out, then I type what i want to insert into database WHEN I CLICK THE SUBMIT BUTTON, ONCE THE SUBMIT BUTTON IS CLICKED IT CLOSES THE CURRENT WINDOW AND THEN USING JAVASCRIPT or AJAX show whether the query was successful or not in another page which I specified

I don't know if it will be successfully done,
as in click the  SUBMIT button the new popped out window closes and then the  result of the QUERY IN PHP is shown in a separate page, appearing for some seconds and then disappears.

Thanks all
I am totally new to Ajax and Javascript, so don't mind my dumb question.

Comment: Sorry, your dumb question has offended me greatly.

Comment: This question is a bit open ended.  It'd be a lot easier for us to help you if you showed us some code you've written to attempt to achieve the effect you desire, so we can help steer you towards better / working implementations.  Right now you're basically asking us to write it for you, which isn't appropriate.  This is not a freelance site, it's a Q&A.

Comment: @blockhead - use of the `<sarcasm>` tag might be warranted there :-). user1008593, what have you tried ... and were is it breaking?

Comment: I admit that i need to post a little code but like I said I don't know where to start from (novice stated up remember) - Had it been PHP ASP, VB.net or JAVA I wouldn't post without sample of what I have tried to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

page with form (u need [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) framework):

```
<form id="submit-form">
    ...
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submit-form").submit(
    function() {
            my_window.close(); // close your popup
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.post("query.php", {
            data: data },
            function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        );
        return false;
    }
);
</script>
```

page query.php:

```
$sql = ... // make it using $_POST
if(mysql_query($sql)) {
    echo "Success !";
}else{
    echo "Failure. :(";
}
```